# Csv file search speedup

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

[image]

I need to build a relief profile graph by coordinates, I have a csv file with 12,000,000 lines. searching through a csv file of the same height takes about 2 - 2.5 seconds. I rewrote the csv to parquet and it helped me save some time, it takes about 1.7 - 1 second to find one height. However, I need to build a profile for 500 - 2000 values, which makes the time very long. In the future, you may have to increase the base of the csv file, which will slow down this process even more. In this regard, my question is, is it possible to somehow reduce the processing time of values?
Code example:

```
import dask.dataframe as dk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

filename = 'n46_e032_1arc_v3.csv'

df = dk.read_csv(filename)
df.to_parquet('n46_e032_1arc_v3_parquet')

Latitude1y, Longitude1x = 46.6276, 32.5942
Latitude2y, Longitude2x = 46.6451, 32.6781
sec, steps, k = 0.00027778, 1, 11.73
Latitude, Longitude = [Latitude1y], [Longitude1x]
sin, cos = Latitude2y - Latitude1y, Longitude2x - Longitude1x
y, x = Latitude1y, Longitude1x
while Latitude[-1] < Latitude2y and Longitude[-1] < Longitude2x:
    y, x, steps = y + sec * k * sin, x + sec * k * cos, steps + 1
    Latitude.append(y)
    Longitude.append(x)

time_start = time.time()
long, elevation_data = [], []
df2 = dk.read_parquet('n46_e032_1arc_v3_parquet')
for i in range(steps + 1):
    elevation_line = df2[(Longitude[i] <= df2['x']) & (df2['x'] <= Longitude[i] + sec) &
                    (Latitude[i] <= df2['y']) & (df2['y'] <= Latitude[i] + sec)].compute()
    elevation = np.asarray(elevation_line.z.tolist())
    if elevation[-1] < 0:
        elevation_data.append(0)
    else:
        elevation_data.append(elevation[-1])
    long.append(30 * i)

plt.bar(long, elevation_data, width = 30)
plt.show()
print(time.time() - time_start)
```

Comment: How are the variables `steps`, `Longitude`, and `Latitude` defined?

Comment: It was a good idea to share a sample of the data, and describe the problem using that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So, you want to query a bunch of points in a line, and find the nearest elevation for each x and y value, right? Am I understanding the question right? If so, that suggests that either using a raster or a KD tree could make this much faster.

Comment: @Nick ODell 
Added code and data photo

Comment: I recently started learning python, could you send me an example code or simple documentation on raster and KD tree? @Nick ODell

Comment: when asking a question, please don't upload pictures of data/code/errors/logs/etc, for a [variety of reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/). instead, paste them into your question as a code block, or better yet, generate sample data using code as a [mre]. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to solve this problem using KD trees. A KD tree is a data structure for doing fast nearest-neighbor searches.

```
import scipy.spatial

tree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(df[['x', 'y']].values)
elevations = df['z'].values

long, elevation_data = [], []
for i in range(steps):
    lon, lat = Longitude[i], Latitude[i]
    dist, idx = tree.query([lon, lat])
    elevation = elevations[idx]
    if elevation < 0:
        elevation = 0
    elevation_data.append(elevation)
    long.append(30 * i)
```

Note: if you can make assumptions about the data, like "all of the points in the CSV are equally spaced," faster algorithms are possible.

Comment: This is definitely the right approach if your data is full of unstructured collections of points

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data might be on a regular grid. If (and only if) every combination of x and y exist in your data, then it probably makes sense to turn this into a labeled 2D array of points, after which querying the correct position will be very fast.

For this, I'll use [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/), which is essentially pandas for N-dimensional data, and integrates well with dask:

```py
# bring the dataframe into memory
df = dk.read('n46_e032_1arc_v3_parquet').compute()

da = df.set_index(["y", "x"]).z.to_xarray()

# now you can query the nearest points:
desired_lats = xr.DataArray([46.6276, 46.6451], dims=["point"])
desired_lons = xr.DataArray([32.5942, 32.6781], dims=["point"])

subset = da.sel(y=desired_lats, x=desired_lons, method="nearest")

# if you'd like, you can return to pandas:
subset_s = subset.to_series()

# you could do this only once, and save the reshaped array as a zarr store:
ds = da.to_dataset(name="elevation")
ds.to_zarr("n46_e032_1arc_v3.zarr")
```